# Server side paging in MVC3 telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am working with telerik radGrid with MVC3 Aspx engine with partial view an my grid data are binding with ViewModel but i am facing issue with Paging and sorting on server side.

please help me out to acheive this task.

please tell me steps, which i have to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid) contains pretty extensive examples. You may also take a look at the [following thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/server-side-paging-sorting-without-ajax.aspx).